# Showing a popup when page loads in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am very new to Angular and I am trying to make a popup in Angular 4 that asks for the user's email when the page loads. I googled and I couldn't find a single example. What is the best service I can use for that task, how is it usually done?

Comment: use libraries like primeng, ng-bootstrap, angular material , etc . these libraries have many components including PopUp which u can use it in your project

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on? Creating the actual popup, or getting it to display on load?

Comment: Making it display on load and closing it

Comment: @RogerCrowley so, what is "it"? Which of the libraries displaying popups are you using? Where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

Using Bootstrap you can use below method.

```js
First install ngx-bootstrap npm module using below CLI command.
npm install ngx-bootstrap


Now import ngx-bootstap module in your root module like this :
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@NgModule({ 
  imports: [
    ModalModule.forRoot()
  ]
});


Than import that module in your ts file and use it like this :
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap';

// @ViewChild('Same name as your html #Model name') define any name : ModalDirective;
@ViewChild('myModel') myModel: ModalDirective;


// Now use this code to when you want open model :
this.myModel.show();

// Now use this code to when you want hide model :
this.myModel.hide();

In your case you need to call like this
  
ngOnInit(){
  this.myModel.show();
}
```

```html
In Your HTML File paste this code :

<div class="modal fade" bsModal #myModel="bs-modal"
    tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">        
        ..
        // Write your html here      
        ..
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fire up the terminal and type : npm install @ngui/overlay

In your app.module.ts:

```
import { appComponent      } from './app.component';    
import { NguiOverlayModule } from '@ngui/overlay';

@NgModule
({
  declarations: [appComponent     ],
  imports:      [NguiOverlayModule]
});
```

In your app.component.ts:

```
import { NguiOverlayManager } from '@ngui/overlay';
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';

@Component
({
    selector    : 'app-root',
    templateUrl : './app.component.html'
})
export class appComponent  implements OnInit
{ 
    constructor
    (
        public  _overlayManager : NguiOverlayManager
    ){}

    openPopUp()
    {
        this._overlayManager.open('popup-modal', 1);
    }
    closePopUp()
    {
        this._overlayManager.close('popup-modal');
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.openPopUp();
    }
}
```

In your app.component.html:

```
<div id="popup-modal" ngui-overlay-of="window">
   <!-- Popup content goes here -->
</div>
```